# More than one option for a custom arrow head in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'd like to set more than one option for a custom arrowhead by means of the `pgfsetarrowoptions` command. Is it possible? How can I do? And then, how can I catch the values with the `pgfgetarrowoptions` command.

For example, imagine that I need to change both the angle and the color of the tip in the following example, from the `pgfmanual`:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\newlength\arrowsize
\pgfarrowsdeclare{var arc}{var arc} % options is an angle
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfarrowsleftextend{-4\arrowsize-.5\pgflinewidth}
\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin % fix join
\pgfsetroundcap % fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpatharc{-90}{-180+\pgfgetarrowoptions{var arc}}{4\arrowsize}
\pgfusepathqstroke
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpatharc{90}{180-\pgfgetarrowoptions{var arc}}{4\arrowsize}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-2,-4) grid (1,4);
\foreach \option in {-60,-50,...,60}
{
\pgfsetarrowoptions{var arc}{\option}
\draw[ultra thick,-var arc] (-2,\option/15) -- (0,\option/15);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think loading everything into one variable can be an alternative if there are not too many properties to be shipped to the arrow macro. Here is a proof of concept. I didn't pay too much attention to variable packing health and convenience but it does the job for this example.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\newlength\arrowsize
\def\getmyoptions#1/#2/{
\xdef\optionone{#1}%
\xdef\optiontwo{#2}%
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{var arc}{var arc} % options is an angle
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfarrowsleftextend{-4\arrowsize-.5\pgflinewidth}
\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\getmyoptions\pgfgetarrowoptions{var arc}}\temp
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin % fix join
\pgfsetroundcap % fix cap
\pgfsetstrokecolor{blue!\optiontwo}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpatharc{-90}{-180+\optionone}{4\arrowsize}
\pgfusepathqstroke
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpatharc{90}{180-\optionone}{4\arrowsize}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-3,-4) grid (1,2);
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{-10*\x}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xk}{5*\x}
\edef\option{\xj/\xk/}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{var arc}{\option}
\draw[ultra thick,-var arc] (-2 cm,2cm - \xk mm) -- (0,2cm - \xk mm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]